# Is it possible to measure HBA throughput using Perfmon on Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, storage-area-network, fiber

I have a server with two round-robin 4GB HBAs to a fiber switch and was wondering if I can measure activity/throughput on these HBAs using Perfmon? If so, which counters would I use? I initially thought Network, but perhaps I'd have to do something with PhysicalDisk.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PerfMon measures this with the `Physical disk performance object -> Avg. Disk sec/Transfer` or `/Read`, or `/Write` counters.

This accounts for the time spent on the following:

1. Class Driver – manages the device type, such as disks, tapes, etc.
2. Port Driver – manages the transport protocol, such as SCSI, FC, SATA, etc.
3. Device Miniport Driver – This is the device driver for the Storage Adapter. It is supplied by the vendor of the device (Raid Controller, and FC HBA).
4. Disk Subsystem – This includes everything below the Device Miniport Driver – This could be as simple as a cable connected to a single physical hard disk, or as complex as a Storage Area Network.

There's more information on TechNet that goes a bit deeper: [Measuring Disk Latency with Windows Performance Monitor](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askcore/archive/2012/02/07/measuring-disk-latency-with-windows-performance-monitor-perfmon.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. I actually just found that myself and feel dumb for even asking.

Comment: its not dumb...as other people find this helpful....like me!